# Where are the save files in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't find those that I need to delete. What's the location of those files?

How can we manage them?

Comment: Not enough reputation to make a post... **For Linux (Wine) players:** `~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/compatdata/[gameid]/` In this case, for Skyrim Special Edition, `[gameid]` is 489830. From there, check `/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/Saved Games/`, `/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/My Documents/`, and `/pfx/drive_c/documents and settings/all users/`. Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/8/1741094390480128995/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Skyrim puts its saves in the following directory in Windows Vista & Windows 7 and Windows 8:

> C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves

Note that on Windows 8, the saves folder could be hidden, so you'll have to show the hidden files to be able to see it.

Skyrim puts saves in the following directory in Windows XP:

> C:\Documents and Settings[UserName]\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves

These files are not dependent on anything so you can freely share them across computers, delete, copy, backup, or anything else.

Comment: Could you add the path for Windows XP?

Comment: I would assume the saves are under `C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`, but I can't confirm

Comment: no you can't just copy them - steam give them different cloaked version numbers
if anybody has an idea what you can do here let us know?

Comment: @gfhdgh: I've used the same save files on two different computers without any issue (copying over with Dropbox). If you are having trouble, feel free to ask a question here so we can help you

Comment: I use Dropbox for this as well, however I've recently gotten an error from Steam that makes me think the game may also be using Steam cloud storage for the save games.  I will have to check and see if that is indeed working.

Comment: Does anyone know if the directory for Windows Vista and 7 is the same for Windows 8? (I'm asking because of this question: [How do I access The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim save files on Windows 8?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/200927/4797))

Comment: You can always get there using windows "shortcuts" in your address line. Your path could be cut and pasted into your File Explorer as follows: file://%UserProfile%/Documents/My Games/Skyrim/Saves

Comment: Note, it's in the same place with Windows 10, also, as Windows Vista through 8.

Answer (score 11):

According to this [forum post](http://www.gameboomers.com/forum/ubbthreads.php/topics/874766/skyrim_windows_8), in Windows 8, the saves are still stored in the same place as Windows 7 (i.e. `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`), however the saves are now **marked as hidden files**.

To unhide the files:

- Open an Explorer window,
- Navigate to the *Skyrim* folder
- Press the 'View' tab
- Check the '*Hidden Items*' checkbox

[image: showing the location of the 'Hidden items' checkbox]

Answer (score 10):

## Locating saves on PC/PS3/XBox for Skyrim

Building on AndyPerfect's and Robotnik's answers, the save files for **Windows** are where they said. I added the rest.

### PC

**Windows XP**

Skyrim puts saves in the following directory in Windows XP:

`C:\Documents and Settings[UserName]\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`

**Windows Vista/Windows 7**

Skyrim puts its saves in the following directory in Windows Vista & Windows 7:

`C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`

**Windows 8**

According to this [forum post](http://www.gameboomers.com/forum/ubbthreads.php/topics/874766/skyrim_windows_8), in Windows 8, the saves are still stored in the same place as Windows 7 (i.e. `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`), however the saves are now marked as hidden files.

To unhide the files:

Open an Explorer window,
Navigate to the Skyrim folder
Press the 'View' tab
Check the 'Hidden Items' checkbox
showing the location of the 'Hidden items' checkbox

[image: showing the location of the 'Hidden items' checkbox]

### PS3

On the XMB, goto the "Game" tab and then the "Saved Data Utility (PS3)" tab.

Inside you can find all of your saves and can copy and edit them by pressing **Triangle**.

### XBox 360

On the XBox, saves are usually found on the HDD, but could be found on USB's too. (If you use them)

See [**here**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/games/manage-games-data) for below tutorial.

> From Xbox Home, go to settings, and then select System.
>   Select Storage.
>
> Select the storage device that contains the content you want to copy, move, or delete
>   **(or look at)**:
>
> - Hard Drive: Your console’s hard drive.
> - Cloud Saved Games: Storage space on our Xbox Live servers. For more information, see Store your saved games in the cloud.
> - USB Storage Device: A USB storage device, such as a USB flash drive plugged into your console. To learn more about USB flash drives, see USB flash drive support for Xbox 360.
> - Memory Unit: A memory unit plugged into your original Xbox 360 console.

Then simply head on down to the Games & Apps section of your choice and your save will be in there.

Comment: Great! was just thinking someone should add stuff for PS3/Xbox :). A couple of things though: Where you state my answer covers Windows - it only covers Windows 8, not all Windows Versions - the other answer covers Windows 7 (where they aren't hidden) and Windows XP (which has a different folder structure). Secondly, Your answer could stand on it's own with the PS3/Xbox stuff (without copying mine verbatim). I'm not complaining, just wondering why you bothered, as it is already in the answer section.

Comment: @Robotnik Well, when it comes to bounties, were all against each other. :P And I only added yours into mine for consistency (With aknowledgment!) I can get rid of it if you want. As for your suggestions. Thankyou, I will look into that now.