# How do I access The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim save files on Windows 8?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I access the Skyrim save data on Windows 8? I need to delete some saves.

I've read this question: "[Where are the save files in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/where-are-the-save-files-in-skyrim)" - but there are no specified directories for Windows 8. (I couldn't find the save files at the mentioned directories in the current answer.)

Comment: No it didnt have windows 8 location on there(Not used to windows 8 but i couldn't find it there)

Comment: It's still the same question, just needs updating for Win8.

Comment: I'd update the answer in that other question first before closing this one. Seems to a more logical process imho.

Comment: @deutschZuid - There's now a bounty on the old question

Comment: @PikaNinja - I've also added an answer to the old question. I hope it helps! :)