# Skyrim different addon configurations for two steam accounts on same computer

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

My girlfriend and I both own Skyrim on Steam. I have the Dawnguard/Hearthfire/Dragonborn DLCs, she doesn't. I was wondering how Steam treats the missing DLCs on her account if we play on the same computer (not at the same time, of course.)

In particular: If she is logged into her Steam account on my computer with all DLCs installed, would she be able to accidentally start some DLC quest and corrupt her savegames so she can't continue on her own computer? Or would Steam correctly disable all DLC content if she is logged in?

Answer (score 3):

I can't really answer since it would require proper testing and I dont know how steam handles multiple accounts, but i can help you play safe meanwhile:

When you launch skyrim, in his launcher, you can disable the DLC by pressing the "DATA FILES" button
[image: Data files]
Now you should be able to see a menu with various files ( mods/addons and DLC'S). 
[image]

If you have the dlc and he recognizes them, you can disable them by clicking on the checkbox ( for example Dawnguard.esm is gonna disable the dawnguard DLC ).

Then press ok and play the game without the DLC's.

For safety, i recommend to make a backup of her data files, copying them somewhere safe before playing
[Backup save files](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/where-are-the-save-files-in-skyrim)