# Is it possible to override Family Share to continue playing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, steam-family-sharing

My family friend shared Skyrim with me and I played for a while. Now, there is an issue and he cant allow me to access it anymore, so I'm wondering, since I already have it downloaded, can I somehow override the feature that prevents me from playing it so I can continue my story?

Answer (score 8):

No. If you want to play the game, you have to buy it. There's no way to override the family sharing protection.

If you're worried about continuing the story, that's a separate issue.  Buying the game would let you continue your story.

Comment: Saved progress however can be moved to newly purchased game, here question about saves location https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/where-are-the-save-files-in-skyrim

Comment: Saved progress is tied to your windows account, unrelated to steam. Fairly sure you don't need to do anything at all for that.